# Fullcalendar - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar v2.6.0 + php + sqlite PDO

Problem:

> fullcalendar.js:10416 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
> at normalizeEventTimes (fullcalendar.js:10416)
> at normalizeEventDates (fullcalendar.js:10385)
> at assignDatesToEvent (fullcalendar.js:10376)
> at buildEventFromInput (fullcalendar.js:10363)
> at Calendar_constructor.renderEvent (fullcalendar.js:10205)
> at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
> at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
> at n.fn.init.$.fn.fullCalendar (fullcalendar.js:32)
> at Object.success (Calendar.php:269)

Get json:

```
{"id":"1","title":"test","start":"2022-03-29","end":"2022-03-29"}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('sqlite:Calendar.db');
$bdd->exec("CREATE TABLE if not exists events (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, start TEXT, end TEXT)");
if(isset( $_POST['title'], $_POST['start'], $_POST['end']))
{   
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end)";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end));

 $requete = "SELECT * FROM events";

 $res = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 echo json_encode($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
?>
```

I am junior. I do not understand what the problem is. Wrong date format?

code:

```
   events: "ajax.php",  

    dayClick: function(date,jsEvent,view){

    var clickDate = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(clickDate);
    form.dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: '30%',
    title: "event",
    buttons: [{
    id: 'add',
    text: 'add',
    click: function() {
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {

               title: event_title.val(),
               start: event_start.val(),
               end: event_end.val()
            },
            success: function(){
                Calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: event_title.val(),
                    start: event_start.val(),
                    end: event_end.val(),
                    allDay: false
                });
            }
        });
        emptyForm();
    }
},
    ...
...
    }]
    });
    event_start.val(clickDate);
    event_end.val(clickDate);
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    formOpen('add');
},
...
...
```

Help make it work(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be treating `event_title`, `event_start` and `event_end` as if they are HTML `<input>` elements, referenced by the jQuery `.val()` syntax, is that correct?

if so, jQuery (or MomentJS which handles the dates) is saying they are undefined.

so you need

```
<input id="event_title" value="">
<input id="event_start" value="">
<input id="event_end" value="">
```

on your page somewhere, and then to reference them `event_title.val(), event_start.val(), event_end.val()` need instead to be

```
$("#event_title").val()
$("#event_start").val()
$("#event_end").val()
```

Comment: hi
it's already done
```
        var event_title = jQuery('#event_title');
        var event_start = jQuery('#event_start');
        var event_end = jQuery('#event_end');
```
`code`

Comment: It turned out that the error was caused by the function emptyForm()
`function emptyForm() { 
event_title.val("");
event_start.val("");
event_end.val("");}`